# Change img src with jQuery without loading the image multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I wrote a script using jQuery that changes the src attribute of an img tag in HTML when the window is resized and it works correctly. However, using Chrome's developer tools I noticed that *each* time that window is resized, the actual image is loaded! In other words, if a user repeteadly resizes the window, the images will be loaded again and again. Is there a way to avoid that, so that images are loaded at most once?

Here's my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $(".on-demand-img").attr("src", "http://img1.coastalliving.timeinc.net/sites/default/files/image/2012/06/beaches/0612_best-beaches-kapalua-m.jpg");
} else if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $(".on-demand-img").attr("src", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fa/6f/9a/fa6f9a5f7577a578bb7d63bf458d2905.jpg");
} else {
    $(".on-demand-img").attr("src", "https://imageserver.avenso.com/imageserver/bilder/paesaggi-sole-scattered-clouds-0:0:4b04507422128:1b762d.jpg");
}
});
```

Comment: maybe debounce would be a good use case here https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Sure that’s not just due to the fact that you have “Disable cache (while DevTools is open)” enabled in dev tools settings …?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I've just checked and cache is enabled

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik the debounce function would just pospone the loading of the image, not prevent it

Comment: Use `srcset` or `picture` depending on your use case (resolution switching or art direction). For non supporting browsers there good working polyfill solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function setImageSrc(img, src){
    //images have a src-property you should use, 
    //instead of messing with the attribute
    $(img).each(function(){
        this.src === src || (this.src = src);
    });

    /*
    $(img).filter(function(){
        return this.src !== src;
    }).attr('src', src);
    */
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    setImageSrc(".on-demand-img", 
        w <= 480? "http://img1.coastalliving.timeinc.net/sites/default/files/image/2012/06/beaches/0612_best-beaches-kapalua-m.jpg":
        w <= 768? "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fa/6f/9a/fa6f9a5f7577a578bb7d63bf458d2905.jpg":
        "https://imageserver.avenso.com/imageserver/bilder/paesaggi-sole-scattered-clouds-0:0:4b04507422128:1b762d.jpg"
    );
});
```

**Edit:** still has a error, i've found. The src-property always contains the full path; code will fail with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Things like these need to be done via css:

Basically, you build your dom in a way that covers everything and then, via mediaqueries, you display what you want.

Another, more elegant, solution could be using [`srcset`](https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/) [but IE doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset)

```css
.visible-xs,
.visible-lg,
.visible-sm { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .visible-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .visible-sm {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .visible-lg {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="visible-lg" src="pat/to/lg" alt="BIG IMAGE">
<img class="visible-sm" src="pat/to/sm" alt="MEDIUM IMAGE">
<img class="visible-xs" src="pat/to/xs" alt="SMALL IMAGE">
```

Comment: Thank you @Hitmands, this was what I did at the beginning but then I noticed that the three images are loaded together. Since I'm working on a responsive website I would like to load only one image and chnage it if the window is resized